# Flex library not loaded Magento

Tags: magento

We moved a Magento webshop from one host to another yesterday. Everything went well. But when we login to the admin panel we get an error "Flex library not loaded" And it happens every time we go to a new page.

I already checked file permissions for js/lib etc. with no luck.

I emptied the cache with no luck either...
So I'm kinda running out of options here.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the flex.js file from `/js/lib/` folder ?

Comment: @DependencyHell fixed it already. There was a .htaccess file in /js/lib that was for some reason blocking everything. Thanks anyways!